# Does QStringList store data on stack or on heap?

Tags: qt, stack, heap-memory, qstring, qstringlist

In the code below:

```
void fun()
{
    QString aa("aa");
    QString bb("bb");
    QStringList a;
    a<<aa;
    a<<bb;
}
```

I know QString stores its data on heap, but how about QStringList? Does it allocate an array on stack, or on heap and only store the pointer to the array on stack?

Comment: As per the documentation, `QStringList` inherits from [`QList<QString>`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details).  The relevant details are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QList technically is:

```
class QList
{
    QListData::Data* p;
};
```

where QListData::Data is:

```
struct Data 
{
    QtPrivate::RefCount ref;
    int alloc, begin, end;
    void *array[1];
};
```

So QList itself allocates memory on the heap and stores a pointer to it.

Comment: I think array[0] points to the  data of an item allocated on heap, right? But I did not see a chain pointer linking every item of the list. p only points to the first item in the list?

Comment: That's because QList is not a _list_. QList is more like a vector but with a weird strategy of storing items bigger than `sizeof(pointer)`. Linked list is called QLinkedList

Comment: Do you mean all list items are stored in the "array" of struct Data? If we create a local QStringList variable, it only occupies 8 bytes on the stack(in 64 bit system)?

Comment: Correct. Items are stored in the heap-allocated array. QList itself is just `sizeof(pointer)` bytes on the stack